# Load data table using dropdown select value

Tags: php, datatable

I am trying to load a data-table using drop-down select value. But code not seems to be working. I am saving the drop-down value in hidden field on its on-change and redirecting but new_id is null. Below is my code.

HTML

```
    <input type="hidden" id="id_abc">
    <select id="abc" name="abc" class="form-control" onchange="xyz(this);">
    <option>-- Select --</option>
    </select>
```

JS

```
    $(document).ready(function() {

         var new_id = $('#id_abc').val();

         if(new_id)
         {
            //GET DATA TABLE USING new_id

         }
    });

    function xyz(id)
    {
       $('#id_abc').val(id.value);
       //show the table
       var url =_PATH_+'?id='+id.value ;
       window.location = url; // redirect

    }
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think your problem is `id.value` . 
Try this `var url =_PATH_+'?id='+$(id).val();` on your `function xyz(id)`

Comment: No value is saved in hidden field but not fetched in new_id while page reloads.

Comment: Then you must get it from URL

Comment: Thanks for reply.. I am trying the same.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/19491336/6068342
If you need some help :)